# Embedding $\beta X$ in $\mathbb{N}^{\kappa}$ for some cardinal $\kappa$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

I found an interesting exercise but I don't know how to solve it.

Given a topological space $X$, suposse that there exist $\lambda$ a cardinal such that $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subset of $\mathbb{N}^{\lambda}$ ($X$ can be viewed, in fact, as a closed subset of $\mathbb{N}^{\lambda}$). Is there $\kappa$ a cardinal such that $\beta X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{N}^{\kappa}$? Here, the subspace is not necesarilly closed nor open. It's only a subspace of $\mathbb{N}^{\kappa}$.

I really don't know how to solve it. Is it true? My first attempt was take $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}^{\lambda}$ with $X$ closed in $\mathbb{N}^{\lambda}$. By the Tychonoffness of $\mathbb{N}^{\lambda}$ then such space can be viewed as a subspace of $[0,1]^{\alpha}$ for some cardinal $\alpha$, i.e., $\mathbb{N}^{\lambda}\subseteq [0,1]^{\alpha}$. Then $X\subseteq \mathbb{N}^{\lambda}\subseteq [0,1]^{\alpha}$. If we take the closure respect to $Z=[0,1]^{\alpha}$, i.e., $$\text{cl}_{Z}(X)\subseteq\text{cl}_{Z}(\mathbb{N}^{\lambda})\subseteq [0,1]^{\alpha}$$
Can be $\text{cl}_{Z}(X)=\beta X$? From here I don't know how to go because $\text{cl}_{Z}(\mathbb{N}^{\lambda})$, in general, is not of the form $\mathbb{N}^{\kappa}$. Any hint? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This seems not to bad to sort out when $X$ is strongly zero-dimensional. I don't know the answer in general, since there are $\mathbb{N}$-compact spaces of positive topological dimension (see for instance [Mysior](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-092-04/S0002-9939-1984-0760954-1/S0002-9939-1984-0760954-1.pdf)). btw, note that $\beta X$ is compact, so if it embeds in $\mathbb{N}^\kappa$, then it does so as a closed subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a space is called $\mathbb{N}$-compact, if it can be embedded as a closed subset of $\mathbb{N}^{\lambda}$ for some cardinal $\lambda$.
Note that a compact subset of $\mathbb{N}^{\lambda}$ is closed in $\mathbb{N}^{\lambda}$, hence $\mathbb{N}$-compact. 
With this notation the question is, when $\beta X$ is $\mathbb{N}$-compact.
In fact, Tyrone already almost pointed out the answer, namely:

Let X be completely regular. Then $\beta X$ is $\mathbb{N}$-compact, iff $X$ is strongly $0$-dimensional.

*Proof:*
"$\Rightarrow$":
Obviously, $\beta X$ is $0$-dimensional. Hence, $X$ is strongly $0$-dimensional. 
"$\Leftarrow$": Since $X$ is strongly $0$-dimensional, $\beta X$ is strongly $0$-dimensional. Since it is compact, in particular, realcompact, it is
$\mathbb{N}$-compact. (This is a well-known result proven in 1967 by H. Herrlich. I couldn't find an online version of the proof, but it is cited, for instance, [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183532816), and also mentioned in the paper of [Mysior](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-092-04/S0002-9939-1984-0760954-1/S0002-9939-1984-0760954-1.pdf) mentioned by Tyrone.)

The example given in [Mysior](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-092-04/S0002-9939-1984-0760954-1) is $\mathbb{N}$-compact, but not strongly $0$-dimensional, hence $\beta X$ is not $\mathbb{N}$-compact, thus answering the assumption in the negative.